# Removing duplicate columns while loading csv using java spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to join two tables in java spark, one of the tables contains duplicate columns. The problem is that the columns are renamed with trailing numbers, hence the `dropDuplicates()` function doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")
            .load(path);
data.dropDuplicates();
```

The problem is that the duplicate columns in the table are already renamed with trailing numbers, so no duplicates are removed.
What is the right way to handle it?

- I'm using spark-sql_2.11-2.3.0

Comment: dropDuplicates removes duplicate rows. Probably you are looking for [drop](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#drop-java.lang.String...-)?

Comment: @werner I don't want to list the columns to drop, I want the duplicate columns automatically removed.

Answer (score 0):

Group all column names by the suffix (without the trailing numbers) and then take only one (random) column from each group. This list of column names can then be used to select the columns before the join.

```java
String[] allFieldNames = data.schema().fieldNames();        
String[] selected = Stream.of(allFieldNames)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.replaceAll("^[0-9]*", ""), Function.identity(), (a, b) -> b)).values()
  .toArray(new String[0]);

Dataset<Row> dfWithUniqueCols = data.select(selected[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(selected, 1, selected.length));
```

Comment: It might not work if I have columns with trailing numbers in the original table, there might be columns which are mapped to the same one. Isn't there a native way to drop duplicates?

Comment: I am not aware of such a function.